# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}_{X}[f(X)] = \mathbb{E}_{X, Y}[f(X)]$?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Suppose $p(x, y)$ has $x$-marginal $p(x)$ and that $f(x)$ is a well-behaved function. Is it always true that the expectation with respect to the joint distribution is equal to the expectation with respect to the marginal if $f$ depends only on that variable?
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x, y)}[f(x)] \overset{?}{=} \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f(x)]
$$
If it is not always true, under which conditions is it?

---

I am aware that working with densities may be misleading and perhaps a measure-theoretic treatment may be preferred. Hence let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ be two measurable spaces. Let $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{X}$ be a random variable with distribution $P_X$. Also, let $(\mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{Y})$ be the product space and $\pi$ be a measure on it having $x$-marginal $P_X$ on $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$, that is
$$
\pi(A\times\mathsf{Y}) = P_X(A) \qquad \qquad\qquad\forall A\in\mathcal{X}.
$$
Is this true?
$$
\int_\mathsf{X} f(x) P_X(dx) \overset{?}{=} \int_{\mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{Y}} f(x) \pi(dx, dy)
$$

##### Attempted Proof

The expectation of $f\circ X$ can be written as follows using the change of variables formula
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_\Omega f\circ X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_\mathsf{X} f(x) dP_X(x) = \mathbb{E}_X[f].
$$
Is it possible to write the RHS also as $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$? Perhaps if one could use something similar to Fubini's theorem then
$$
\int_{\mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{Y}} f(x) \pi(dx, dy) = \int_{\mathsf{X}} f(x) \int_\mathsf{Y} \pi(dx, dy) = \int_\mathsf{X} f(x) \pi(dx, \mathsf{Y}) = \int_\mathsf{X} f(x) P_X(dx)
$$
but of course, the question is whether this is appropriate or not.

Comment: This is utterly trivial: since you are working with the marginal, $y$ is irrelevant and can be dropped from the notation.